# Unable to get environment variables using os python

Tags: python, apache-spark, environment-variables, python-os

I recently created two environment variables in my terminal as shown below

```
export SPARK_HOME='/opt/spark/'
export HAIL_HOME='/home/ABCD/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/envs/bio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hail/'
```

When I use `echo $SPARK_HOME` or `echo $HAIL_HOME`, I am able to see the path as output

But, when I use the below os commands in `jupyter notebook`

```
os.getenv('SPARK_HOME')  # able to get the output /opt/spark/
os.getenv('HAIL_HOME')   # returns no output
```

I also tried defining the same variables from `jupyter` as well using `os.putenv` but even then,I see output only for `SPARK_HOME`

However, I am able to see in my terminal screen the environment variables`SPARK_HOME` and `HAIL_HOME` using `printenv` command

Can help me understand what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that it doesn't produce output for `HAIL_HOME` because it is installed in my `virtual environment`. (see `.pyenv` which is a hidden folder for my virtual environment`)

However, if anyone can confirm this it's even better

Answer (score 0):

use os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME").

Comment: Sorry, my question is on why doesn't it work for `HAIL_HOME`? When I type `os.environ.get("HAIL_HOME")`, I get blank/no output

Comment: *** Works for both env may be you have to see some process not overriding your exisiting environment variable.*